# Why is the Performance score of an empty, default NextJS Application so low?

Tags: javascript, performance, next.js, lighthouse

I started playing around with my first Next.js project.

After creating a new project via `create-next-app`, I ran the performance-tab in the web-app 'Lighthouse' (the results can be viewed in the tabs below). The performance report returned a score of 79, however; all the other test were above 90.

Can someone explain to me why these are the results?

The project is newly created, and totally empty, one would assume a performance report to return a great score for such a project, but it did not. If you have any insight that could help to clarify why the performance test is returning with the results that I explained above, it will be appreciated. Thank you!

[image: Performance Results Image(a)]

[image: Performance Results Image(b)]

Comment: All of the suggestions are out there. Please search on google for each topic and you'll get ways to resolve the issue. I've done the same to my projects.

Comment: You're right, I changed the title and description.

Comment: This is a fine question @MarcoMazzai. And it deserves an answer from the Google Lighthouse team if you ask me.

Comment: Do you have the react developer tools addon installed? For me that's the reason for _Remove unused JavaScript_. 
Also, are you using the dev server or the production build?

Comment: Your questions is really relevant. Next should be better, faster, on a fresh project. That means that we must work more on every project to try to "clean" next things. Would be better to have a "performance ready" next.

Answer (score 7):

I think you are running the test on the development server. **In the development mode, there are a lot of unused js codes are being used**. That's why the performance is a bit slow. You can check the production build.

All you have to do is:

1. run **`npm build`**
2. **`npm start`** (if your dev server is running on port 3000, then run **`npm start -p 5000`**)
3. then go to **`http://localhost:5000`** and run the lighthouse. I think the performance will be better.

Comment: Yeah but you still can't examine the built site in dev, right? IMO, I think this is a more fundamental problem with Lighthouse. In dev mode, you can't ascertain the performance of your app. You almost have to deploy it first.

Comment: Might be. But I think we can. Cause we are not in dev mode anymore if we used the production build. Yeah, there might be some issues with the capacity of the machine. But from the code perspective, I think there should not be any performance drop.

Comment: The way Next works, if you're in dev mode and using `getStaticProps` each call is still a fetch to the server. See here: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#runs-on-every-request-in-development. I think the issue is with how Lighthouse works and it's a fundamental flaw, unless I'm missing something.